# Point In polygon using geootools

Tags: java, coordinates, geotools

I'm trying to extract a area of geopoints by drawing a polygon from 3 or more coordinates to set my logical geoFence but the thing is that I think that LinearRing needs all the points on  to close the object anyway can anyone give me an insight of what am I doing wrong

```
Coordinate[] coordinates = vertices;    
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(PrecisionModel.FIXED), 4326);
LinearRing linearRing = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(coordinates);   
Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(linearRing, null);
setGeometry(polygon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that a LinearRing (and a polygon) must be a [closed ring](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/LinearRing.html) - it needs a minimum of 4 points and the first and last point must be the same. So I would do something like:

```
Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[vertices.length+1];
for(int i=0;i<vertices.length;i++){
    coordinate[i] = vertices[i];
}
coordinate[vertices.length] = coordinate[0];
 .....
```

Comment: Tanks I already did that but after closing my polygin I cant seem to get to get a true value on the method contains when I now that the point is inside the region of the polygon

Comment: probably a projection issue then